# Auto layout does not work with items placed in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I have placed three buttons in Storyboard. But they do not stretch to the screen size. I want to stretch (resize) it proprtionally to the screen size. So, they should look relatively the same on iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus. Use Auto Layout and Use Size Classes are turned on.

[image]

**EDIT**

If I press ADD MISSING CONSTRAINTS, it looks like the second picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, make sure you add some constraints to your objects.

I made a test project with your example, I managed to get the desired result by adding the following constraints.

[image: Constraints Example]

I suggest you read up on [Storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html) and [Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).